# Is to possible to auto redirect the browser to a specified website if the entered address is not available?

Tags: c#, .net

What i'm trying to do is to make changes to the default google chrome / firefox / iexplore page that shows that the site is unavailable when some incorrect web address is typed  :

[image]

So instead of showing the page above, it will show some website like http://www.google.com

How to do this for Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer ? Where does these default webpages are stored and how to change them.. Thankyou in advance

Comment: Are you talking about a DNS timeout, a lack of `A` record, or a 404?

Comment: These are user settings, hands off.

Comment: @SLaks I'm talking about when i mistype a web address something like www.ggogldsdk.com

Comment: What does this have to do with C# and .net? As @SLaks said if we are talking custom 404 then I understand, but what you seem to be describing is a DNS setting.

Comment: Do you want something like, when user on your site enters some invalid page, then you want to show a customized error page or google default page ?

Comment: For user's in general, or users on say a corporate network.  If you're in control of the dns server you can do something like this.

Comment: @emd i need to create a simple windows form application which will automatically do this changes upon execution.

Comment: @ShikataGaNai Unless you're running the winforms app on the DNS server itself, or your DNS has some sort of exposed settings api this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question as it is posed: No.

Since the `DNS` server typically redirects unresolvable requests, you would need to be running your `winforms` application on the DNS server itself in order to change the redirect.

Now to offer some other alternatives:

- Try making a browser extension that redirects on 404
- Try making a winforms app that programmatically changes the `DNS` to a different one (eg opendns with a custom 404 page)

Or perhaps just check out Open DNS if all you need to do is change to a DNS with a custom 404.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own browser you can display whatever you want when a 404 error is returned.  As far as I know, chrome/ie/firefox don't allow you to customize this error page, and as others have said, you'd need to have access to the DNS server to change this when any browser is used.